# Set text on the same y-aligment line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been stuck on this problem for hours.

This is my `Header.js`

```
  <div className="navbar-inner">
      <h2>Text1</h2>
      <h3>Text2</h3>
  </div>
```

This is my `Header.css` file:

```
.navbar-inner {
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   width: 87vw;
   background-color: red;
   justify-content: space-between;
   vertical-align: sub;
}
```

This is what is shown:

[image]

I would like Text1 and Text2 to be aligned on the same y-line:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align-items` is what you need for vertically aligning text when using flex box.

I also removed the margin from the h2 and h3 elements (it is there by default).

```
.navbar-inner {
   margin: 0 auto;
   color: #fff;
   display: flex;
   width: 87vw;
   background-color: red;
   justify-content: space-between;

   /* New styles */
   align-items: flex-end;
   padding: 5px;
}

h2, h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

You will probably need to adjust the padding to align it how you actually want it in terms of how close the text should be to the edges.

Answer (score 2):

You can give flex on h2 and h3 tag.

```
h2, h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```